# CSS: Control space between bullet and <li>

Tags: html, css, html-lists

I'd like to control how much horizontal space a bullet pushes its `<li>` to the right in an `<ol>` or `<ul>`.

That is, instead of always having

```
*  Some list text goes
   here.
```

I'd like to be able to change that to be

```
*         Some list text goes
          here.
```

or

```
*Some list text goes
 here.
```

I looked around but could only find instructions for shifting the entire block left or right, for example, http://www.alistapart.com/articles/taminglists/

Comment: Almost a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2441059/how-to-reduce-default-gap-between-bullet-and-text-in-li

Answer (score 212, accepted):

Put its content in a `span` which is relatively positioned, then you can control the space by the `left` property of the `span`.

```css
li span {
  position: relative;
  left: -10px;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li><span>item 1</span></li>
  <li><span>item 2</span></li>
  <li><span>item 3</span></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Just to clarify, the <span> tag can be semantic when it is assigned a class, for instance <span class="tel">123-456-7890</span> is implicitly semantic.

Comment: +1 for actually answering the guy's question ;) (though the span should ideally in real life have a class anyway for good practice futureproofing as well as semantics: if in future any javascript or new features development etc had a good reason to add extra spans to your content, things could get messy)

Comment: in firefox there is not display properly text is overlapping the bullets using this trick

Comment: @ingyhere I doub't this is true, since I cannot find anything that proves this claim. Can you provide any sources?

Comment: @Wolle Hmmm. It's an old comment, and I'm not sure of the concern -- If it's as to whether `<SPAN>` can utilize `id` or `class` tags, take a look at [W3C](https://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/global.html#edef-SPAN). If the question is whether it can convey semantic meaning, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/278952/325452). Technically, the `<SPAN>` tag is a non-semantic inline element by itself, but in some way that affords more flexibility in its re-use. Nowadays, I believe one can use the `inline-block` descriptor to allow a lot greater range of formatting options.

Comment: @ingyhere, I remember there was originally a comment of someone who downvoted and complained for using a "non-semantic" element in the answer, referring to the span. That comment has apparently been deleted, causing the rest of comments being slightly out of context. Probably we'd better have a moderator to cleanup all comments.

Answer (score 158):

To summarise the other answers here – if you want finer control over the space between bullets and the text in a `<li>` list item, your options are:

**(1) Use a background image:**

```
<style type="text/css">
li {
    list-style-type:none;
    background-image:url(bullet.png);
}
</style>

<ul>
    <li>Some text</li>
</ul>
```

Advantages:

- You can use any image you want for the bullet
- You can use CSS `background-position` to position the image pretty much anywhere you want in relation to the text, using pixels, ems or %

Disadvantages:

- Adds an extra (albeit small) image file to your page, increasing the page weight
- If a user increases the text size on their browser, the bullet will stay at the original size. It'll also likely get further out of position as the text size increases
- If you're developing a 'responsive' layout using only percentages for widths, it could be difficult to get the bullet exactly where you want it over a range of screen widths

**2. Use padding on the `<li>` tag**

```
<style type="text/css">
ul {padding-left:1em}
li {padding-left:1em}
</style>

<ul>
    <li>Some text</li>
</ul>
```

Advantages:

- No image = 1 less file to download
- By adjusting the padding on the `<li>`, you can add as much *extra* horizontal space between the bullet and the text as you like
- If the user increases the text size, the spacing and bullet size should scale proportionally

Disadvantages:

- Can't move the bullet any closer to the text than the browser default
- Limited to shapes and sizes of CSS's built-in bullet types
- Bullet must be same colour as the text
- No control over vertical positioning of the bullet

**(3) Wrap the text in an extra `<span>` element**

```
<style type="text/css">
li {
    padding-left:1em;
    color:#f00; /* red bullet */
}
li span {
    display:block;
    margin-left:-0.5em;
    color:#000; /* black text */
}
</style>

<ul>
    <li><span>Some text</span></li>
</ul>
```

Advantages:

- No image = 1 less file to download
- You get more control over the position of the bullet than with option (2) – you can move it closer to the text (although despite my best efforts it seems you can't alter the vertical position by adding `padding-top` to the `<span>`. Someone else may have a workaround for this, though...)
- The bullet can be a different colour to the text
- If the user increases their text size, the bullet should scale in proportion (providing you set the padding & margin in ems not px)

Disadvantages:

- Requires an extra unsemantic element (this will probably lose you more friends on SO than it will in real life ;) but it's annoying for those who like their code to be as lean and efficient as possible, and it violates the separation of presentation and content that HTML / CSS is supposed to offer)
- No control over the size and shape of the bullet

Here's hoping for some new list-style features in CSS4, so we can create smarter bullets without resorting to images or exta mark-up :)

Comment: Great answer. For #2 to work, be sure you maintain your list-style-position to `outside`.

Comment: The span element is the fix for me.  I +1'ed this answer only because I preferred negative margin to negative absolute positioning - for no good reason.

Comment: If you have text that wraps lines I found that I had to add `display: block;` to the span element for so the wrapped text would line up as well ( I also ended up using anchor tags instead of spans )

Comment: Using background images for anything that is not just that is almost always a very bad idea. They can't be saved, are not printed and not mentioned by screen readers. Using <span> ist most elegant way to solve this. paddings will not work as they also change position of the bullets.

Comment: I would NEVER use background image for this. You can always use the :before element with the content: "•"; then, you use padding and absolute position on that before element to control it.

Answer (score 63):

This should do it. Be sure to set your bullets to the outside. you can also use CSS pseudo elements if you can drop them in IE7 downward. I don't really recommend using pseudo elements for this kinda thing but it does work to control distance.

```css
ul {
  list-style: circle outside;
  width: 100px;
}

li {
  padding-left: 40px;
}

.pseudo,
.pseudo ul {
  list-style: none;
}

.pseudo li {
  position: relative;
}

/* use ISO 10646 for content http://la.remifa.so/unicode/named-entities.html */
.pseudo li:before {
  content: '\2192';
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>Any Browser really</li>
  <li>List item
    <ul>
      <li>List item</li>
      <li>List item</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>

<ul class="pseudo">
  <li>IE8+ only</li>
  <li>List item
    <ul>
      <li>List item with two lines of text for the example.</li>
      <li>List item</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: I can't believe this answer isn't accepted. It's 100% CSS, it doesn't add any superfluous <span> element, and it made me finally understand why there is a inside/outside option ! (and it's the accepted answer of the duplicate question mentioned...)

Comment: Using `list-style-position: outside` and padding on the `LI` elements allows you to increase the distance between the bullet points but it still doesn't work the other way around beyond a browser specified offset. See [this JS Bin](http://jsbin.com/EHoK/2/edit?html,css,output).

Comment: Addendum: In modern browsers (IE9+, FF, Chrome, etc.), use a negative `text-indent` on the `<UL>` or `<LI>` to negate the browser enforced distance between bullet point and `<LI>` content. That is, increase `padding-left` as shown above to increase the distance and reduce `text-indent` to reduce the distance between the bullet point and the content as desired.

Comment: **Alas**, for all of the above mentioned desktop browsers, if the contents of an `<LI>` wraps into a second line, such subsequent lines end up being re-indented based on the margin/padding/indent that we managed to undo for the first line via `text-indent`. _Sigh_

Comment: another option is to use the :before pseudo elements and set the content to whatever you like. from there position the pseudo elements as desired.

Comment: Mesagoma, it's still a good trick, thanks, for single line non wrapping li content it's easy and perfect, and even if it does wrap, all that happens is that the second line starts a little further from the bullet, no big deal.

Comment: Best answer since CSS invention

Comment: Like @MindTailor said, this is probably the best answer here.

Answer (score 23):

You can use the `padding-left` attribute on the list items (**not** on the list itself!).

Comment: Please note this only works if the `list-style-position` is set to the default `outside`.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer, at least for normal usage. It avoids using a `<span>` element just for design purpose.

Comment: @eukras Unfortunately, it shouldn't, as it only allows _more_ space.

Answer (score 23):

There seems to be a much cleaner solution if you only want to reduce the spacing between the bullet point and the text:

```
li:before {
    content: "";
    margin-left: -0.5rem;
}
```

Comment: This should be the accepted answer; I wasted a lot of time trying to adapt the hacks above.

Comment: This doesn't work well with multi-line bullets, where the original spacing takes effect after the first line.

Answer (score 18):

Old question, but the :before pseudo element works well here.

```
<style>
    li:before {
        content: "";
        display: inline-block;
        height: 1rem;  // or px or em or whatever
        width: .5rem;  // or whatever space you want
    }
</style>
```

It works really well and doesn't require many extra rules or html.

```
<ul>
    <li>Some content</li>
    <li>Some other content</li>
</ul>
```

Cheers!

Comment: Nice & simple answer. I would add that setting `margin-left: -5px` (or whatever value) will decrease the space between the bullet and the `<li>` element

Comment: Note: This does not support hanging indents

Comment: Awesome answer, this worked perfectly with the most minimal amount of work! Thanks!

Answer (score 18):

For **list-style-type: inline**:

It's almost the same like DSMann8's answer but less css code.

You just need to

```
<style>
    li:before {
        content: "";
        padding-left: 10px;
    }
</style>

<ul>
    <li>Some content</li>
</ul>
```

Cheers

Comment: This works for `list-style-position: inside` too, which is great!

Comment: If you want the spacing to be smaller you can use `margin-left: -10px` property.

Answer (score 11):

Here is another solution using css counter and pseudo elements. I find it more elegant as it doesn't require use of extra html markup nor css classes :

```css
    ol,
    ul {
        list-style-position: inside;
    }
    
    li {
        list-style-type: none;
    }
    
    ol {
        counter-reset: ol; //reset the counter for every new ol
    }
    
    ul li:before {
            content: '\2022 \00a0 \00a0 \00a0'; //bullet unicode followed by 3 non breakable spaces
    }
    
    ol li:before {
            counter-increment: ol;
            content: counter(ol) '.\00a0 \00a0 \00a0'; //css counter followed by a dot and 3 non breakable spaces
    }
```

I use non breakable spaces so that the spacing only affects the first line of my list elements (if the list element is more than one line long). You could use padding here instead.

Answer (score 10):

The following solution works well when you want to move the **text closer to the bullet** and even if you have multiple lines of text.

`margin-right` allows you to move the text closer to the bullet

`text-indent` ensures that multiple lines of text still line up correctly

```css
li:before {
  content: "";
  margin-right: -5px; /* Adjust this to move text closer to the bullet */
}

li {
  text-indent: 5px; /* Aligns second line of text */
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li> Item 1 ... </li>
  <li> Item 2 ... this item has tons and tons of text that causes a second line! Notice how even the second line is lined up with the first!</li>
  <li> Item 3 ... </li>
</ul>
```

[image]

Answer (score 7):

Using text-indent on li works best.

text-indent: -x px; will move the bullet closer to li and vice-versa.

Using relative on span the negative left might not work properly with older versions for IE.
P.S- avoid giving positions as much as you can.

Comment: This behaves strange on Chrome. Snaps to little space at -5px;

Answer (score 6):

Old question but still relevant.
I recommend using negative **`text-indent`**.
**`list-style-position`** must be `outside`.

Pros:

- Bullet is properly automatically positioned
- Change font size does not break the bullet position
- No extra elements ( no ::pseudo-elements too )
- Works for both RTL and LTR without change in CSS.

Cons:

- try
- to
- find
- one :)

Comment: I tried using this method but the indent doesn't work for me if there are line breaks. Text indent will only indent the first line.

Comment: Trying this in Chrome just now with list style type `outside` (I also tried `inside`) just moves the entire `li` left or right and doesn't move the text closer or farther from the bullet itself. I tried putting the indent on the `ul` and on the `li` and neither had the desired effect.

Answer (score 5):

It seems you can (somewhat) control the spacing using padding on the <li> tag.

```
<style type="text/css">
    li { padding-left: 10px; }
</style>
```

The catch is that it doesn't seem to allow you to scrunch it way-snug like your final example.

For that you could try turning off list-style-type and using &bull;

```
<ul style="list-style-type: none;">
    <li>&bull;Some list text goes here.</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 5):

An unordered list starts with the ul tag. Each list item starts with the 
The list items will be marked with bullets (small black circles) by default:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
       <body>
          <h2>Normal List </h2>
          <ul>
             <li>Coffee</li>
             <li>Tea</li>
             <li>Milk</li>
          </ul>
       </body>
    </html>
```

Output:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<h2>Normal List </h2>

<ul>
  <li>Coffee</li>
  <li>Tea</li>
  <li>Milk</li>
</ul>

</body>
</html>
```

The text-indent property specifies the indentation of the first line in a text-block.
Note: Negative values are allowed. The first line will be indented to the left if the value is negative.

```
<ul style='text-indent: -7px;'>
  <li>Coffee</li>
  <li>Tea</li>
  <li>Milk</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, please try to annotate your solutions though, for ease of others' understanding.

Comment: this is the best answer and should be accepted. minimum CSS!

Comment: Changing the text indent on the `UL` seemed to just move the entire `LI` left or right, bullet included. It did not appear to make the text get closer or farther from the bullet itself, using `inside` or `outside` on the type. Maybe I'm doing something wrong, but I don't see how this works to answer the question.

Answer (score 5):

### Nobody mentioned [::marker](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/::marker) property

It allows to set the space **smaller** than browser default.

```css
ul > li::marker {
  content: '•'; /* as a side effect sets the space to zero */
  font: 1.2em/1 sans-serif; /* adjust the bullet size */
}
ul > li {
  padding-left: .2em; /* have full control over the bullet space */
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>one
  <li>two
  <li>three
</ul>
```

Answer (score 4):

You can also use a background image replacement as an alternative, giving you total control over vertical and horizontal positioning.

See the answer to [this Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2441059/how-to-reduce-default-gap-between-bullet-and-text-in-li)

Answer (score 4):

You can just give a `padding-left` to your `<li>` element.

Comment: Padding-left can increase the space between bullet and text, but not reduce it (in FireFox anyway)

Answer (score 3):

If you'd prefer not to add additional markup e.g. `<span>`, you could use:

1. `list-style-position: inside;` to move the list-style closer to your text from the left
2. And if you still need to pull the list items closer you can use the `::before` selector on the `li` element to move the text toward the bullet.

```
    ul {
        list-style-type: disc;
        list-style-position: inside;
        padding-left: 16px; /* or margin */
    }

    li::before {
        content: '';
        margin-left: -8px;
    }
```

- List item text
- List item text
- List item text
- List item text

Answer (score 2):

You can use CSS property padding-inline-start:

```
li { 
    padding-inline-start: 1em;
}
```

Comment: This solution deserves more credit. Especially now that IE11 is being discontinued.

Answer (score 1):

```
ul
{
list-style-position:inside;
}
```

Definition and Usage

The list-style-position property specifies if the list-item markers should appear inside or outside the content flow.

Source: http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_list-style-position.asp

Comment: This does not answer the question. It asks the method for controlling the size of the indentation.

Answer (score 1):

[More info w3schools](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_bullet_color.asp)
ul {
`list-style: none;`
}

ul li::before {
`content: "\2022";`
`color: black;`
`display: inline-block;`
`width: 8px;`}

Answer (score 1):

It's interesting that most of us reach for `margin`, `padding` and/or `position` properties when faced with a problem like this. I know I did in the past. What if we're looking at it all wrong?

Before I provide a different solution, let's try and understand browser implementations a bit better. If we look at the user agent stylesheet for lists in [WebKit](https://trac.webkit.org/browser/trunk/Source/WebCore/css/html.css), here's what we find:

```
ul, menu, dir {
    //...
    margin-inline-start: 0;
    margin-inline-end: 0;
    padding-inline-start: 40px;
}

ol {
    //...
    margin-inline-start: 0;
    margin-inline-end: 0;
    padding-inline-start: 40px;
}
li {
    display: list-item;
    text-align: match-parent;
}
```

The other browsers are similar. The list indent is provided by padding on the `ul` and `ol`, not the `li`. Also worth noting, there's no negative positioning, margin, or indent anywhere to be found. So what is creating that gap between the bullet and the text?

The answer only becomes clear when we try changing the bullet character itself. I'll use the `list-style-type` property to do this, but instead of giving it a standard value like `disc` (the definition of which is up to the browser, being [a little vague](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-counter-styles-3/#simple-symbolic) in the specs), I'll give it a quoted string value:

```css
ul {
   list-style-type: "•";
}
```

```html
<ul>
   <li>Oh dear</li>
   <li>what happened</li>
   <li>to the bullet spacing?</li>
</ul>
```

We can reintroduce the spacing by adding a standard space character after the bullet"

```css
ul.custom-bulleted {
   list-style-type: "• ";
}
```

```html
<ul class="custom-bulleted">
   <li>Ah, that's better.</li>
   <li>I've never cared for sticky bullets.</li>
</ul>

<ul>
   <li>I'm an unstyled list.</li>
   <li>I never have that problem!</li>
</ul>
```

I can only assume that this is akin to what the browsers are doing internally—inserting whitespace after the bullet and essentially floating the whole thing to the immediate left of each `li`. In fact [the specs](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-counter-styles-3/#simple-symbolic) pretty much confirm this by comparing the default internal implementation to the [`@counter-style`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@counter-style) at-rule which allows us to define our own list types:

> The following stylesheet fragment provides the normative definition of
> these predefined counter styles:
>
> ```
> @counter-style disc {
>   system: cyclic;
>   symbols: \2022;
>   /* • */
>   suffix: " ";
> }
> ```

The whitespace is right there in the `suffix`.

There's one unanswered question though… Why does the unstyled list look different to the `custom-bulleted` class in my example? Again, it seems to come down to [each browser's different internal implementation](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=585381). If you compare them in different browsers, even the custom bullets vary between browsers. What I have found though, is that you can standardise the appearance of a string `list-style-type` simply by declaring a `font-family` on [`li::marker`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/::marker), a feature that wasn't available to us when this question was originally asked.

So, coming back to the original question, if we want to control the space between the bullet and the `li`, we can do so by changing the width of the whitespace character, or by adding multiple whitespace characters, using a string-based [`list-style-type`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/list-style-type), which has [wide browser support](https://caniuse.com/mdn-css_properties_list-style-type_string). Alternatively, we could define a custom list style with [`@counter-style`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@counter-style), but that is not currently supported by Safari.

Unicode offers us a wide range of [whitespace characters](https://unicodeplus.com/category/Zs) to choose from. Here's a list that uses an Em Space (U+2003):

```css
ul {
   list-style-type: "•\002003";
}
```

```html
<ul>
   <li>I like big gaps and I cannot lie</li>
   <li>You other brothers can't deny</li>
</ul>
```

I know this approach is not the first one that springs to mind. We've been so used to aligning things with margins, padding and indents that we tend to reach for those tools every time. But in many ways, the browser's way makes sense. What could be simpler than indenting the whole list with a single padding declaration on the `ul`, and letting the bullet take care of itself? (Maybe one day, the `li::marker` pseudo-element will support padding, for those who reckon they need even more fine-grained control. I won't be holding my breath though.)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `ul li:before` and a background image, and assign `position: relative` and `position:absolute` to the `li` and `li:before`, respectively. This way you can create an image and position it wherever you want relative to the li.

Answer (score 0):

Use `padding-left:1em; text-indent:-1em` for the `<li>` tag.
Then, `list-style-position: inside` for the `<ul>` tag.

```
<ul style='list-style-position: inside;'>
  <li style='padding-left: 1em; text-indent: -1em;'>Item 1</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

If your list-style is `inside` then you could remove the bullet and create your own ... e.g. (in scss!)

```css
            li {
                list-style: none;
                &:before {
                    content: '- ';
                }
            }
```

And if you list style is `outside` then you could do something like this:

```css
            li { 
                padding-left: 10px;
                list-style: none;
                &:before {
                    content: '* '; /* use any character you fancy~! */
                    position: absolute;
                    margin-left: -10px;
                }
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm 99.9999% sure no one cares because this question has been asked 12 years ago, but I needed to solve this just now and here's what I found:

> A trailing space is treated as part of the escape, so use 2 spaces if you actually want to follow the escaped character with a space.

And, indeed, it works!

```
ul.asterisks {
  list-style-type: '\2731\ ';
}
```

Source: [Using character escapes in markup and CSS](https://www.w3.org/International/questions/qa-escapes)

P.S. Maybe this is because I've been at it for so long that I'm losing my mind? Inserting spaces works in the browser's dev view. To actually get the spaces to take I had to...escape...the spaces?? (See above.) Madness. (BTW, Why are all these pages from 2010? What happened in 2010? Wait a minute...12 years ago was...2010. :fear:)

Source: [CSS character escape sequences](https://mathiasbynens.be/notes/css-escapes)

Answer (score 0):

A solution to control the space between numeral and text with respect to widest marking.

Tip: edit the last 'text-align' to get 'inside or 'outside effect. You can remove 'upper-roman' for standard numeral.

```css
ol {
  counter-reset: n;
  display: table-row;
  text-align: left;
}
li {
  counter-increment: n;
  display: table-row;
  text-align: left;
}
li::before {
  content: counter(n, upper-roman) ".";
  display: table-cell;
  padding-right: 1rem;
  text-align: left;
}
```

```html
<ol>
  <li>test1</li>
  <li>test2</li>
  <li>test3</li>
</ol>
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't like either of the solutions presented above.
My solution:

```
li:firts-letter { margin-left: -0.25rem; }
```

Margin value will vary for different fonts