# UL Bullets Showing Outside Frame

Tags: html, css

I'm having some trouble getting the bullets to show up in an unordered list.  If I change the css to display the bullets as inside, they should up, but right next to the text.  What my buddy wants is for the bullets to show up on the far left hand side of the frame and for there to be a couple of tabs worth of space between it and the text.  I've messed with the margins/border/padding quite a bit. bit can't get the bullets exactly where I want them!

I've included my html and css below.

Thanks!
James

The page in question:

http://www.pingdynamic.com/sites/slva/services.html

The CSS:

```
ul {
list-style-type: circle;
list-style-position: outside;
}

li {
margin-left: 50px;
}
```

The HTML:

```
<h2 class="subheading">You Dream It.  We Bring To Life.</h2>
        <br>
        <p>SLVA is proud to offer the following servies:</p>

        <ul>
            <li>Consultation - Let's discuss your goals and ideas and how to achieve them.</li>
            <li>High performance parts, sales and installation.</li>
            <li>Custom body work - From wide-body kits and ground effects to really any custom aesthetic modification you can imagine.</li>
            <li>Custom carbon fiber design, forming and application.</li>
            <li>Custom 3-stage paint work.</li>
            <li>Full fabrication services - We work with all materials (including steel, aluminum, stainless steel) and methods
            (traditional and TIG welding) </li>
            <li>Custom chassis design and modification.</li>
            <li>Custom suspension design, modification and fabrication.</li> 
        </ul>
        </div>
```

Comment: I don't see any bullets

Comment: That's because I am using the "outside" flag.  Had I used "inside" they would show up.

Comment: use list-style-position: inside;

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason you can't see your bullets, is because you have `overflow-x:hidden` in line 10 of your style.css - this is being applied to a whole bunch of elements including `ul` and `li`.

Try something like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>SVLA</title>
    <style>
        ul {
            list-style-type: circle;
            list-style-position: outside;
            margin-left: 10px;
            overflow: visible;
        }

        li {
            padding-left: 50px;
            overflow: visible;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <h2 class="subheading">You Dream It.  We Bring To Life.</h2>
    <br>
    <p>SLVA is proud to offer the following services:</p>
    <ul>
        <li>Consultation - Let's discuss your goals and ideas and how to achieve them.</li>
        <li>High performance parts, sales and installation.</li>
        <li>Custom body work - From wide-body kits and ground effects to really any custom aesthetic modification you can imagine.</li>
    </ul>
</body>
```

Example: http://cssdesk.com/bgCgj

(I added some extra padding and margins to the `ul` and `li` in this example to compensate for the other styles in your page)

Comment: Thank you very much. It helped me to resolve my issue when I could not see the bullet point that had "list-style-position: outside".

Answer (score -1):

Put its content in a span which is relatively positioned, then you can control the space by the left property of the span.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <title>SO question 4373046</title>
        <style>
            li span { position: relative; left: -10px; }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <ul>
            <li><span>item 1</span></li>
            <li><span>item 2</span></li>
            <li><span>item 3</span></li>
        </ul>
    </body>
</html>
```

Source: [CSS: Control space between bullet and <li>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4373046/css-control-space-between-bullet-and-li)

Answer (score -1):

Either use a span and relative positioning like @fkim said, or remove the bullet point and use a pseudo-element to put them back in with padding:

```
ul {
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
}

li {
margin: 0;
list-style-type: none;
}

li:before {
content: "•";
padding-right: 50px;
}
```

Example: http://cssdesk.com/

Comment: This works with two exceptions: 1) The bullet now looks like a diamond with a question mark in it and 2) the text is now wrapping all the way down to the second line next tot the bullet instead of the text: http://i.imgur.com/uO6KSiz.jpg  Thanks for the help, BTW.  I prefer this solution to wrapping each line in a span!

Comment: The reason the bullet is a diamond with a question mark is because of your character encoding (the "•" gets displayed as such) Need to either set UTF-8(?) encoding or check out some other ways to enter it: http://graphemica.com/%C2%B7