# Increase gap between bullet point and text

Tags: html, qt, qtextedit, qtextdocument

When using QGraphicsTextItem for editing and rendering text the distance between bullet points and text (in any kind of list) is very small. Is there any way to increase this?

I tried setting a default style sheet on the QTextDocument but can't find a proper CSS property for this specific change.

Here is a sample of how it looks like. The red arrow shows the gap I am talking about:

[image: Sample image]

Thanks,
Fabian

Comment: Dirty hack: use `&nbsp;` (non-breaking space) to add extra space: `<li>&nbsp;&nbsp;Text</li>`.

Comment: The answer can be found [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4373046/css-control-space-between-bullet-and-li)

Comment: @dvvrd: that post suggest to use the "position" and "left" attributes. I don't think they are support by Qt's HTML subset?

Comment: @Pavel: that works for a programmatic approach. But when the user enters text directly into the QGraphicsTextItem widget then the extra space will not be there...

Comment: Yes, Qt can meet your demand. But I assume that you need to set custom layout.