# How is bullets and numbers' margin calculated when list-style-position:outside?

Tags: css, html-lists, listitem

[image: List item bullet spacing]

I presume it is calculated upon `font-size`'s value. But how? `1ex`? `1em`? Is it consistent across browsers? If no, is it possible to normalize it so that it looks about the same on all browsers?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/dhz92Lb8/

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4373046/css-control-space-between-bullet-and-li

Comment: I would assume it is arbitrary. The bullets themselves are inconsistent, let alone the position of the marker box. CSS2.1 [does not define](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/generate.html#propdef-list-style-position) this position. css-lists-3 does not define a default either, but it will allow controlling the marker box with ::marker.

Comment: @CodeiSir That doesn't answer the question. I'm asking if the margin between the bullet and the content is a predictable value; like, the horizontal size of a "space" character.

Comment: @BoltClock aw. As far as you know, is it possible to override the default behavior entirely using `@counter-style` & co. so that the result is a bit more consistent?

Comment: @Wes: not sure. Never used `@counter-style`.

Answer (score 0):

I made some experimental research: :P

I overlayed a red text with the same font size over the list, and added two blank spaces inbetween "12345." and "List Item":

Font 40px: [image]
Font  20px: [image]

However this is only true for Chrome. Firefox and Edge both do it diffrently on their own:

[image]
[image]

Try it yourself here https://jsfiddle.net/e3hLbbw7/

**Conclusion:** *It not consistent across browsers*, but it scales with the font-size

---

```
<div style="opacity: .5; color: red; position: absolute; top: 20px; left: 27px;">
  12345.&nbsp;&nbsp;List Item
</div>
```