# CSS remove gap between the text and list-style-image

Tags: html, css

For my `ul` list items I added a picture using `list-style-image` property.

example what I have: **[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/9qnmxpjh/)**

```css
ul {
  list-style-image: url('http://placehold.it/50x40');
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>Coffee</li>
  <li>Tea</li>
  <li>Coca Cola</li>
</ul>
```

I would like my text (*e.g.* "Coffee") within the `li` items to touch the pictures - have no gap between the list item image and its description.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can wrap the contents of each `<li>` in a `<span>` and then position that span accordingly:

```
<li><span>Coffee</span></li>
```

And then:

```
li span {
  position: relative;
  left: -7px;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/ndpr9tnr/

Comment: At the end this worked the best with my picture. thanks.

Answer (score 6):

One solution is to remove the list style and add the image before the `li` element via pseudo class `:before`

```css
ul {
  list-style: none;
}

ul li:before {
  content: url(http://placehold.it/50x40);  
  display: inline-block;   
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>Coffee</li>
  <li>Tee</li>
  <li>Cola</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 3):

It seems that you cannot directly control the space between the list-style-image (or bullet) and the li content.

In order to make it happen you can use the image as background

```
li {
  list-style-type: none;
  background-image: url('http://placehold.it/50x40');
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: 15px 15px;
  padding-left: 15px;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/gd2rtb70/

You can also look at [this answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4373046/css-control-space-between-bullet-and-li)

Answer (score 2):

You have to make a CSS trick to get this.

Use

```
background: url();
```

instead of

```
list-style-image
```

property for this
see fiddle [link](https://jsfiddle.net/9qnmxpjh/7/)

Answer (score 1):

i don't think you can do that with list-style-image. You need to create a fake list style instead. Something like this:

```
ul {
    list-style:none;
}

li:before {
  content:"";
  background: url('http://placehold.it/50x40');
  width: 50px;
  display: inline-block;
  height: 40px;
}
```

Demo here: https://jsfiddle.net/9qnmxpjh/6/

Answer (score 1):

Even though you have accepted an answer, I feel that it is far more complicated than it needs to be.

Assuming you do not care about IE8 or lower then I propose:

```css
ul {
  list-style-image: url('http://placehold.it/50x40');
}
li {
  text-indent: -7px; /* also works when solely applied to the <ul> */
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>Coffee</li>
  <li>Tea</li>
  <li>Coca Cola</li>
</ul>
```