# Unordered lists: how can I set the distance between bullets and items?

Tags: html, css

In HTML unordered lists (`ul`), how can I set the distance between markers and items, so as to make it *normal* (that is, as all other similar default distances of ordered and unordered lists)?

```html
<p>Ordered list with "position:inside"</p>
<ol style="list-style-position:inside;">
  <li>A</li>
  <li>B</li>
  <li>C</li>
</ol>

<p><b>Unordered list with "position:inside"</b></p>
<ul style="list-style-position:inside;">
  <li>A</li>
  <li>B</li>
  <li>C</li>
</ul>

<p>Standard lists (without "position:inside")</p>
<ol>
  <li>A</li>
  <li>B</li>
  <li>C</li>
</ol>
<ul>
  <li>A</li>
  <li>B</li>
  <li>C</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Maybe an edit highlighting the case when the list-position is inside ? Nice question by the way

Comment: if inside, i guess padding reset will do, else , reset li to block and use the pseudo :before to set the bullet or a counter that you can size as you wish. not too sure what you expect ? inside and outside look the same or set width used by the bullet/counter ? text-indent could be an hint too

Comment: Is it something similar to the following link?: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4373046/css-control-space-between-bullet-and-li

Comment: Most likely you'll need to write your own custom implementation.

Answer (score 3):

The way I see it you could use something like `:before` and add your specific content (like •   ) to create the illusion of setting the length.

Otherwise I don't see a way of doing what you're asking.

```css
[style="list-style-position:inside;"] li{
  list-style:none;
}

[style="list-style-position:inside;"] li:before{
  content: '•';
  margin-right: 7px; //Optional and adjustable
}
```

```html
    <p>Ordered list with "position:inside"</p>
    <ol style="list-style-position:inside;">
      <li>A</li>
      <li>B</li>
      <li>C</li>
    </ol>

    <p><b>Unordered list with "position:inside"</b></p>
    <ul style="list-style-position:inside;">
      <li>A</li>
      <li>B</li>
      <li>C</li>
    </ul>

    <p>Standard lists (without "position:inside")</p>
    <ol>
      <li>A</li>
      <li>B</li>
      <li>C</li>
    </ol>
    <ul>
      <li>A</li>
      <li>B</li>
      <li>C</li>
    </ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess the extra space on left for `ul` with `list-style-position: inside` is to decorate it differently than the ones with the default positioning.

In order to fight this and make all the `ul` appear identical in style no matter what `list-style-position` is given to them, you may want to follow like below:

```css
ul li {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
}

ul li:before {
  position: absolute;
  left: -1em;
  content: "\2022";
}
```

```html
<h3>Unordered list with "position:inside"</h3>
<ul style="list-style-position:inside;">
  <li>A</li>
  <li>B</li>
  <li>C</li>
</ul>

<h3>Standard lists (without "position:inside")</h3>
<ul>
  <li>A</li>
  <li>B</li>
  <li>C</li>
</ul>
```

But again, if you consider nested `ul`s, you need to think a bit more about it (may have to give a different bullet each level and something like that).

Cheers!

Comment: Nop this way you lose the "inside" behavior https://jsfiddle.net/fu92a8xz/ ... don't use absolute just put an inline element maybe

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to all.

As noted in the comments (link by Jose Fuentes), the quickest/simplest solution is, **probably**, to nest `li`s in the `span`s: this reduces the space of a certain number of pixels (but such arbitrary reduction does not guarantee that the list is consistent with the other lists, because -for the purposes of the aforementioned uniformity- the number you have to subtract may differ from browser to browser and tomorrow than today).

I was hoping there was a way to even out the abnormal distance of `ul` with `position:inside`, but without having to do subtraction (approximate and unreliable over time and with the browser) of the same greater distance.

Thank you all again.

```css
ul.inside {
  list-style-position:inside;
}

 ul.inside span {
  margin-left: -15px;
}
```

```html
<p>Ordered list with "position:inside"</p>
<ol style="list-style-position:inside;">
  <li>A</li>
  <li>B</li>
  <li>C</li>
</ol>

<p><b>Unordered list with "position:inside"</b></p>
<ul style="list-style-position:inside;">
  <li>A</li>
  <li>B</li>
  <li>C</li>
</ul>

<p><b>OK Unordered list with "position:inside"</b></p>
<ul class="inside">
  <li><span>A</span></li>
  <li><span>B</span></li>
  <li><span>C</span></li>
</ul>

<p>Standard lists (without "position:inside")</p>
<ol>
  <li>A</li>
  <li>B</li>
  <li>C</li>
</ol>
<ul>
  <li>A</li>
  <li>B</li>
  <li>C</li>
</ul>
```