# Increasing gap size between bullet doesn't shift everything

Tags: css

sSo I wanted to increase size in my list between bullet and text and used:

```css
ul li span { margin-left: 10px; }
```

```html
    <ul>
        <li>
            <span>Text</span>
        </li>
    </ul>
```

And it shifts only lines with bullet:

[image]

How to shift everything properly?

Comment: Have you tried padding on the `li`?

Comment: please provide some jsbin example. In current situation as I understand you not put bullet near last item.

Comment: span is inline element

Comment: @TemaniAfif what should I change to?

Comment: inline-block ...

Answer (score 2):

### Solution 1

Simply use padding on the li, like this:

```css
ul li { padding-left: 100px; }
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>
    <span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec gravida turpis aliquam risus sodales volutpat. Vivamus bibendum urna nunc, non pharetra urna aliquam sed. Maecenas vel diam ultricies, porttitor tortor ac, tincidunt felis. Cras nec lectus est. Praesent eget elementum ipsum. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae; Duis lacus erat, feugiat et enim sed, efficitur tempus justo.</span>
  </li>
</ul>
```

The reason this works (and the margin on the span does not) is because the `li` has default display setting of `block`, while a spans default is `inline`. The latter only applies the margin to the beginning of the line.

---

### Solution 2

Setting the span to block solves this problem too. This avoids any confusion about where the padding should be (left or right of the bullet). This confusion can be the cause of different browser implementations of padding on a li-item. This solution looks/works like this:

```css
ul li span { display: block; padding-left: 100px; }
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>
    <span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec gravida turpis aliquam risus sodales volutpat. Vivamus bibendum urna nunc, non pharetra urna aliquam sed. Maecenas vel diam ultricies, porttitor tortor ac, tincidunt felis. Cras nec lectus est. Praesent eget elementum ipsum. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae; Duis lacus erat, feugiat et enim sed, efficitur tempus justo.</span>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: It shifts everything. Not only text.

Comment: @FaustasButkus What browser are you using? Looks fine on FF and chrome

Comment: @Huangism I'm parsing to pdf, so maybe thats why

Comment: Check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4373046/css-control-space-between-bullet-and-li  it has multiple solutions, changing the span to block or inline-block both works with padding or margin

Answer (score 1):

It works with this css:
`ul li span { margin-left: 10px; display: inline-block; }`