# In list tag align disc to center

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1wRFx.jpg)
The space remove between disc and text.
In this I will use Some class tag, some css styles.
I am using Visual code for the editing this code.

```
<section class="bg-light" id="team">
  <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
          <div class="col-lg-12 text-center">
              <h3 class="section-heading text-uppercase" style="color: black;font-size: 32px;font-weight: bold;">Our Amazing Team</h3>
              <h6 class="section-subheading text-muted" style="color:gray !important"><i>"Great things in business are never done by one person. They're done by a team of people" - Steve jobs</i></h6>
          </div>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
          <div class="col-lg-3">
              <div class="team-member">
                  <img class="mx-auto rounded-circle" src="img/team/Arun.jpg" alt="">
                  <h4 style="font-size: 25px;"><a href="arunrana.html"><b style="color: black">Arun  </b></a></h4>
                  <p class="text-muted">Founder & Lead DevOps</p>
                  <ul style="font-size: 12px;">  
                    <li>B.E. (Computer Engg.)</li>
                    <li>10 Years of Experience</li>
                  </ul>
               </div>
          </div>
      </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: It looks like you have some padding on ul/li elements. Can you reproduce it in https://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: Please provide CSS code too.

Comment: Plz provide html and css code with demo..

Comment: The default bootstrap template works fine. Must be something in your css. https://jsfiddle.net/aq9Laaew/303835/

Comment: when I run your code with bootstrap-4 it work perfectly:https://jsfiddle.net/2syom3wn/

Comment: Almost a duplicate of (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4373046/css-control-space-between-bullet-and-li) , (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4373046/css-control-space-between-bullet-and-li)

Comment: also after your update work perfectly:https://jsfiddle.net/2syom3wn/1/

Comment: Possible duplicate of [CSS: Control space between bullet and <li>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4373046/css-control-space-between-bullet-and-li)

Comment: Thanks !!! for the investing time for me , Again Thanks!!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

**pls try this code**

```html
<html>
<head>
    <style>
        ul {
            list-style-position: inside;
            padding-left: 0;
        }
        li span{
            position: relative; left: -10px;
        }
    </style>

</head>    

<body>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-3">
            <div class="team-member">
                <img class="mx-auto rounded-circle" src="img/team/Arun.jpg" alt="">
                <h4 style="font-size: 25px;"><a href="arunrana.html"><b style="color: black">Arun  </b></a></h4>
                <p class="text-muted">Founder & Lead DevOps</p>
                <ul style="font-size: 12px;">  
                    <li><span>B.E. (Computer Engg.)</span></li>
                    <li><span>10 Years of Experience</span></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [text-indent](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/text-indent)

```css
li {
  text-indent: -10px;
}
```

```html
<section class="bg-light" id="team">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-lg-12 text-center">
        <h3 class="section-heading text-uppercase" style="color: black;font-size: 32px;font-weight: bold;">Our Amazing Team</h3>
        <h6 class="section-subheading text-muted" style="color:gray !important"><i>"Great things in business are never done by one person. They're done by a team of people" - Steve jobs</i></h6>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-lg-3">
        <div class="team-member">
          <img class="mx-auto rounded-circle" src="img/team/Arun.jpg" alt="">
          <h4 style="font-size: 25px;"><a href="arunrana.html"><b style="color: black">Arun  </b></a></h4>
          <p class="text-muted">Founder &amp; Lead DevOps</p>
          <ul style="font-size: 12px;">  
            <li>B.E. (Computer Engg.)</li>
            <li>10 Years of Experience</li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: @Pritesh I have updated my code with your given code. `text-indent: -10px;` works fine here. Run the code snippet.

Answer (score 0):

you can use negative text-index like `text-indent: -6px;` on li tag to remove the space.

Answer (score 0):

This looks like center aligned text

Try adding class `text-left` in `ul`

```
<div class="team-member">
                  <img class="mx-auto rounded-circle" src="img/team/Arun.jpg" alt="">
                  <h4 style="font-size: 25px;"><a href="arunrana.html"><b style="color: black">Arun  </b></a></h4>
                  <p class="text-muted">Founder & Lead DevOps</p>
                  <ul class="text-left" style="font-size: 12px;">  
                    <li>B.E. (Computer Engg.)</li>
                    <li>10 Years of Experience</li>
                  </ul>
               </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
li span { position: relative; left: -10px; }
```

```html
<div class="row">
          <div class="col-lg-3">
              <div class="team-member">
                  <img class="mx-auto rounded-circle" src="img/team/Arun.jpg" alt="">
                  <h4 style="font-size: 25px;"><a href="arunrana.html"><b style="color: black">Arun  </b></a></h4>
                  <p class="text-muted">Founder & Lead DevOps</p>
                  <ul style="font-size: 12px;">  
                    <li><span>B.E. (Computer Engg.)</span></li>
                    <li><span>10 Years of Experience</span></li>
                  </ul>
               </div>
          </div>
      </div>
```

Please use `span` inside the `li`

**CSS:**

```
<style>
         li span { position: relative; left: -10px; }
     </style>
```

**HTML :**

```
<div class="row">
          <div class="col-lg-3">
              <div class="team-member">
                  <img class="mx-auto rounded-circle" src="img/team/Arun.jpg" alt="">
                  <h4 style="font-size: 25px;"><a href="arunrana.html"><b style="color: black">Arun  </b></a></h4>
                  <p class="text-muted">Founder & Lead DevOps</p>
                  <ul style="font-size: 12px;">  
                    <li><span>B.E. (Computer Engg.)</span></li>
                    <li><span>10 Years of Experience</span></li>
                  </ul>
               </div>
          </div>
      </div>
```

**Output Image :**

[image]

Comment: You are welcome. If my answer helps you, please upvote it