# How to set spacing for specific bullets?

Tags: python, css, python-sphinx, markup, restructuredtext

I can change spacing from left's to right's - but this isn't desired for all bullets. reST offers [several](https://docutils.sourceforge.io/docs/ref/rst/restructuredtext.html#bullet-lists) bullet symbols; is it possible to set different spacing for different symbols (in separate unordered lists)?

[image]

```css
/* docs/build/html/_static/css/custom.css */
li {position: relative;
    margin-top: -10px;
    margin-bottom: -10px;}
```

```py
# .py function docstring
"""
If `savepath` file exists,

    - True -> replace it
    - False -> don't replace it

"""
```

E.g. replacing both `-` with `+` would change spacing.

---

**Edit**: How my question differs from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4373046/css-control-space-between-bullet-and-li): I'm using reStructuredText, not markdown.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [CSS: Control space between bullet and <li>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4373046/css-control-space-between-bullet-and-li)

Comment: What exactly you want to achieve? It looks you ask how to control visual appearing of bullet list in HTML. This is not RST related question, but we could still help you.

Comment: Different "bullet symbols" like "*", "+", "-", "•", "‣", or "⁃" doesn't mean how bullet item will look like, but just you can choose from these symbols to denote list item in RST source.

Comment: @Matt Different bullet symbols giving different spacing, globally; i.e. I shouldn't have to dedicate a piece of RST to a specific bullet list. I'm aware that's not what different bullets do as-is, but they _could_ with proper code, and I could write such code, though it'd not be worth the effort - so if something like this wasn't implemented or can't be easily implemented, so be it.