# Space between <li> and bullet

Tags: html, css, html-lists

I'm pretty new so please be kind with me :p
I checked similar topics but couldn't have the wanted result even if I tried.

I have an issue with the space between bullets and li :

[How it looks](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NieKg.png)

I want it to be near to the bullet,but there is this space ...

HTML code :

```
       <section class="section">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-12">
                <div class="text-center">
                    <h2><span class="font-weight-300">Нашы </span> сервисы</h2>
                    <p class="text-muted mt-3"><b>ЧТО МЫ ПРЕДЛАГАЕМ </b>
                       <div class="Order">
                          <ul>
                          <li> <span>Помощь в выборе вузов;</span></li>
                          <li>  Онлайн регистрация;</li>
                           <li>Контакт с вузами и уточнение всех вопросов;</li>
                           <li> Польский присяжный перевод на территории Польши;</li>
                             <li> Подготовка и подача документов;</li>
                           <li> 100% результат поступления.</li>
                           <li> Регистрации на стипендиальные программы.</li>
                          <li> Регистрация в общежитие;</li>
                          <li> Регистрация на курс польского языка.</li>
                         </ul>
                      </div> 
                        
                        <br> maecenas egestas massa sollicitudin rhoncus.</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

CSS code :

```
    .Order {
  display: flex;
  align-items: flex-start;
  margin: auto;
  width: 50%;
  border: 3px solid rgba(71, 63, 63, 0.185);
  padding: 10px;
}
```

Can you help me to manage it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

.order ul li {text-align:left} would do the change.

Comment: @AlexLanez, I think the link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4373046/css-control-space-between-bullet-and-li will help you.