# Unorder list marker behaiviour as a word (inline)

Tags: html, css

Hi i'm trying to recreate this design but I don't know how to apply the style to achieve this. I'm trying with the ul tag but without success.
This is the reference image.

[image]

```css
.item-container{
  width: 260px;
}
```

```html
<ul class="item-container">
  <li class="item">Te realizaremos algunas preguntas para validar tu identidad</li>
  <li class="item">Luego te enviaremos un código de verificación y un enlace</li>
  <li class="item">Accedé al enlace y seguí los pasos</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: There is the code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure what you mean by "I'm trying to recreate this design"
Because if you want an unordered list you can just do:

```html
<ul>
    <li>Hello</li>
    <li>Hi</li>  
    <li>How are you</li>
</ul>
```

Though if you're trying to make it so overflowing text gets sent back under the  bullet, you can add this CSS:

```css
ul {
    width: 100px;
    list-style-position: inside;
}
```

Then up to you to style it as you wish

Comment: Yes it work, but I can't remove the space between the bullet and the text. Is it that possible?

Comment: @STUCKED I found a link to a [useful ressource](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4373046/css-control-space-between-bullet-and-li) that might help you!

Comment: A negative margin do the work, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I really don't get exactly what you're looking for. Could it be:

**The bullet's style?**

in that case, that's the default style for `<li>` elements:
`{list-style-type: disc;}`

**You mean the vertical distance between each list element?**

that could be achieved by a simple `<br>` element, as in the example, or by adding some margin. Also can be done by `display: flex` (here is a very good [reference](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/))

**You want the lines to end exactly where they do in the example?**

In this example, I did it by adding a `widht: 50%` to the `<li>` elements, but not sure if that will work in your case.
There are other ways to do this, but just with this we get the same results as in the example

**You want fonts to be the same?**

Just add  `font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;` to the `<li>` elements.

Please, add some more details on what you need, what you've done and what you're looking to achieve

```css
li{
  width: 40%;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}
```

```html
<ul>
    <li>Te realizaremos algunas preguntas para validar tu identidad.</li>
<br>
    <li>Luego te enviaremos un correo con un código de verificación y un enlace.</li>
<br>
    <li>Accedé al enlace y seguí los pasos</li>
    </ul>
```