# Set the li vertical position

Tags: css

I want to the li bullet is close to the red vertical border that is ul border. Now there is big space between the bullet and red vertical line.  I tried to use margin and padding but it doesn't work. Would some tell me how to do it.

The output of my code
[image]

There is my code:

```css
    li span {
       display:inline-block;
       vertical-align:middle;<!--from  w  w w.  ja v a2  s.  c  o  m-->   
        
    }
     
    .more {
       background-color:Chartreuse;
       height:51px;
       line-height:41px;
    }

    .moretwo {
       background-color:yellow;
       height:51px;
       vertical-align:sub;
    }
```

```html
      <ul style="border-style: solid; border-width: 1px; border-color: red;"> 
       <li class="more"> <span>Lor</span> </li> 
       <li class="moretwo"> <span>Lor</span> </li> 
       <li class="more"> <span>Lor</span> </li> 
      </ul>
```

Comment: You need to add `padding-left:0;` to the <ul> element to move the bullets over. Try adding this to your stylesheet: `ul{padding-left:0;}`

Comment: @user819774 I have updated the code in the answer. Try that

Comment: Does this answer your question? [CSS: Control space between bullet and <li>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4373046/css-control-space-between-bullet-and-li)

Answer (score 0):

Your span definition is into ul, so it only affect what is into it:

```css
ul {
  margin:0px; padding:0px 
}

li span {
  display:inline-block;
  vertical-align:middle;<!--from  w  w w.  ja v a2  s.  c  o  m-->   
   
}

.more {
  background-color:Chartreuse;
  height:51px;
  line-height:41px; margin:0px;padding:0px

}

.moretwo {
  background-color:yellow;
  height:51px;
  vertical-align:sub;
}
```

```html
<ul style="border-style: solid; border-width: 1px; border-color: red;">
  <li class="more"><span>Lor</span></li>
  <li class="moretwo"><span>Lor</span></li>
  <li class="more"><span>Lor</span></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Although your code is good, you are absolutely not explaining why it works. You should provide a little more context to help out make your answer stand out.

Answer (score 0):

By default, **ul element** has **padding: left of 40px**. So, you can change its value to move the **bullets** close to the border. Here is the updated code:-

```css
    ul{
      padding-left: 20px;
    }
    li span {
       display:inline-block;
       vertical-align:middle;<!--from  w  w w.  ja v a2  s.  c  o  m-->   
        
    }
     
    .more {
       background-color:Chartreuse;
       height:51px;
       line-height:41px;
    }

    .moretwo {
       background-color:yellow;
       height:51px;
       vertical-align:sub;
    }
```

```html
      <ul style="border-style: solid; border-width: 1px; border-color: red;"> 
       <li class="more"> <span>Lor</span> </li> 
       <li class="moretwo"> <span>Lor</span> </li> 
       <li class="more"> <span>Lor</span> </li> 
      </ul>
```

I have given **padding-left: 20px to ul** element. You can adjust it as you wish. Hope it will be helpul.

Answer (score 0):

1. First approach is to remove the default left padding and change the [position](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/list-style-position) of the bullets on the `ul`.

```css
ul {
    list-style-position: inside;
    padding-left: 0;
}
```

```css
ul {
    list-style-position: inside;
    padding-left: 0;
}

li span {
   display:inline-block;
   vertical-align:middle;
}

.more {
    background-color: Chartreuse;
    height: 51px;
    line-height: 41px;
}

.moretwo {
    background-color: yellow;
    height: 51px;
    vertical-align: sub;
}
```

```html
<ul style="border-style: solid; border-width: 1px; border-color: red;"> 
    <li class="more"> <span>Lor</span> </li> 
    <li class="moretwo"> <span>Lor</span> </li> 
    <li class="more"> <span>Lor</span> </li> 
</ul>
```

2. Second approach will give you more control of the spacing by overriding the left padding.

```css
ul {
    padding-left: 15px;
}
```

```css
ul {
    padding-left: 15px;
}

li span {
    display:inline-block;
    vertical-align:middle;
}

.more {
    background-color: Chartreuse;
    height: 51px;
    line-height: 41px;
}

.moretwo {
    background-color: yellow;
    height: 51px;
    vertical-align: sub;
}
```

```html
<ul style="border-style: solid; border-width: 1px; border-color: red;"> 
    <li class="more"> <span>Lor</span> </li> 
    <li class="moretwo"> <span>Lor</span> </li> 
    <li class="more"> <span>Lor</span> </li> 
</ul>
```